# Import Realm as module to modify

Tags: android, android-studio, realm, realm-mobile-platform, android-studio-import

I need to modify [realm-java](https://github.com/realm/realm-java). But simple adding realm-library as module to my android studio does not work. Tell which parts of this repo have to be added to my project, so I could use code locally. If it's possible, provide well-detailed guide.

Comment: well that's a bit tricky because you need to compile the Realm-Core as well which requires Linux or MacOS. So unfortunately I won't be able to help you with this.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce what if I'll create a fork, change some lines in a few files? And then just connect my current project not to realm.io account, but to mine github acc with those code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The realm-java repo contains multiple independent modules that must be opened separately in Android Studio.

I would recommend reading https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/README.md#gotchas which describe the layout.

In particular, you need to do:

```
git clone https://github.com/realm/realm-java.git --recursive
cd realm-java
./gradlew assemble
./gradlew installRealmJava // Examples will now work
// Import /realm-java/examples as seperate project
// Import /realm-java/realm as seperate project
```